# difference between static block vs main method in java

Tags: java

my question is simple, why we need the `main()` method?. jvm call `public static void main()` method to start application. as well as static block also executed after classes loaded. without `main()` the program gives `main method not found exception` but you can avoid this error by adding `System.exit(0)` line at the static block after your statements, then whats the point of `main()` method?. is there any functionality's not available without main method?

```
class A{

public static void main(String ar[]){
.....
....
}

// VS

static{
....
...

System.exit(0);  // to avoid main method not found error

}

}
```

Comment: The only reason the exception is avoided is because you told the JVM to exit before it finished looking for `main()`. Also, I'm somewhat skeptical that you would be able to accomplish all your work during the class loading phase...

Comment: You also make the class with the hacked static block (class `A`) unable . I'd be very dubious using any instances of it before it has finished being initialised

Comment: A large number of things are more difficult when getting rid of the main method. What advantages do you see?

Comment: I'm not sure where to ask this, but I wonder if it is possible to construct a situation where a static initializer block cannot replicate the functionality of `public static void main()`, allowing any and all hacks...

Comment: @user3580294 I think if you put it as the very last thing you should be relatively safe. But even that falls down if you are using a class which itself had a hacked static block (after all you can use classes which have their own mains currently)

Comment: @RichardTingle True... Guess this is another one of those things that go on the can-do-but-never-should pile...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `static` block is not executed *after* the class has been loaded.  It is executed *while* the class is being loaded.  Until the static block exits, the class is not fully constructed.

-------- Edit ----------

@sky, try running this program, and see what happens:

```
class Foo {
    static String name = "Michael";
    static {
        Thread t = new Thread(new Bar());
        t.start();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(30000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }
}

class Bar implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(Foo.name);
    }
}
```

Comment: i dont think so, static block is called after the class loader finish its job.

Comment: @sky Class initialization, including the execution of static blocks, is done in the process of class loading

Comment: @sky Anything static below the hacked static block won't be initialised yet for a start. You add an unnessisary headache for no reason. What advantages would using a hacked static block bring?

Comment: Michael 
Process finished with exit code 0   this is the output, and i got ur point

Comment: @RichardTingle I think this question is mostly argumentative.  Haha

Answer (score 3):

Certainly you lose some functionality.  How are you going to get the command-line arguments?  There might be some clever trick to do so, but there's no need to make some hack for it.

The reason to have a standard `main` method across all applications is so that the JVM always knows where to look in a project for the block to begin execution.  You have to have that standardized *somewhere*.

Comment: static block also can be found by virtual machine and what the big deal with command line arguments? i can get inputs by other ways..

Comment: @sky Let me turn your question around.  Why would you want to use a `static` block to run your program and jump through all those hoops?

Answer (score 0):

Well I haven't given much thought to the question in scene however just by looking at the face of it, you cannot at least have command line arguments without a **main()** method.

Comment: alternatively i can get arguments by other ways.( like input dialog or scanner etc..)

Comment: Those won't be command line arguments. (Don't assume command-line args are no big deal)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned there is the issue where command line arguments are impossible or needlessly difficult to access.

There are also the issue of programs with multiple mains in different classes. Sometimes I will create a separate main method to do initial testing of a new class. If I had to put that within the static initialisation block then every intended start point of the program would run whenever that class is loaded; this would be a new source of bugs for no benefit.

It also adds one more complexity of class initialisation that anything below the static initialisation block will have their default value rather than their set values. For example the following prints 0.

```
static{
    HackedStaticBlock h=new HackedStaticBlock();
}
static int badNumber=17;

public HackedStaticBlock() {
    System.out.println(badNumber);

}
```

This is something you sometimes need to worry about with static initialisation but this means you need to worry about it in every program.